# Issue with awslogs service and CloudWatch Logs Agent on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On one of my AWS ec2 instances running Ubuntu 16.04, I'm getting the following errors filled up in my /var/syslog.

```
Jul 17 18:11:21 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: Stopped The CloudWatch Logs agent.
Jul 17 18:11:21 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: Started The CloudWatch Logs agent.
Jul 17 18:11:26 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: awslogs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jul 17 18:11:26 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: awslogs.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 17 18:11:26 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: awslogs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 17 18:11:26 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: awslogs.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 17 18:11:26 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: Stopped The CloudWatch Logs agent.
Jul 17 18:11:26 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: Started The CloudWatch Logs agent.
Jul 17 18:11:32 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: awslogs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jul 17 18:11:32 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: awslogs.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 17 18:11:32 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: awslogs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 17 18:11:32 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: awslogs.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 17 18:11:32 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: Stopped The CloudWatch Logs agent.
Jul 17 18:11:32 Mysql-Slave systemd[1]: Started The CloudWatch Logs agent.
```

The /var/log/awslogs.log contains these messages:

```
database is locked
2018-07-17 20:59:01,055 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 27074 - MainThread - Missing or invalid value for use_gzip_http_content_encoding config. Defaulting to using gzip encoding.
2018-07-17 20:59:01,055 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 27074 - MainThread - Using default logging configuration.

database is locked
2018-07-17 20:59:06,549 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 27104 - MainThread - Missing or invalid value for use_gzip_http_content_encoding config. Defaulting to using gzip encoding.
2018-07-17 20:59:06,549 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 27104 - MainThread - Using default logging configuration.

database is locked
2018-07-17 20:59:12,054 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 27110 - MainThread - Missing or invalid value for use_gzip_http_content_encoding config. Defaulting to using gzip encoding.
2018-07-17 20:59:12,054 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 27110 - MainThread - Using default logging configuration.
```

Any pointers in troubleshooting this will be of great help.

Comment: Try looking at the actual agent log file, `/var/log/awslogs.log` for more information about what the issue is.

Comment: Edited the post to add snippet from /var/log/awslogs.log

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A similar issue was posted in the following link - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=165134

I did the following:

a) Stopped the `awslogs` service

```
$ service awslogs stop  ## Amazon Linux
```

OR

```
$ service awslogsd stop  ## Amazon Linux 2
```

b) Deleted the agent-state file in /var/awslogs/state/ (I renamed it in my case)

```
$  mv agent-state agent-state.old  ## Amazon Linux
```

OR

```
$ cd /var/lib/awslogs; mv agent-stat agent-stat.old  ## Amazon Linux 2
```

c) Restarted the awslogs service

```
$ service awslogs start  ## Amazon Linux
```

OR

```
$ sudo systemctl start awslogsd  ## Amazon Linux 2
```

A new agent-state file was created as a result and the errors mentioned my post disappeared after this.

Comment: see also [Quick Start: Install and configure the CloudWatch Logs agent on a running EC2 Linux instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) and [CloudWatch Logs agent reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html)

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following commands based on your Linux version

sudo service awslogs start

If you are running Amazon Linux 2, try the below command
sudo systemctl start awslogsd
took me 2 hours to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found duplicate entries for some properties in `/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf` file.
(Not all were duplicates, as some of the properties were commented, and I uncommented them to set values.)

It didn't work. Then I scrolled till the bottom of the file.
I found following entries. Set the values to these properties and it worked.

```
[/var/log/messages]
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
file = /home/ec2-user/application.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = MyProject
```